# What's wrong with my MQ Explorer？

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

I upgraded my previous MQ V6.0 to MQ 7.0 a few days ago. But once upgrade completed, MQ Explorer can not display local QMGR in the Queue Manages. I have to add local QMGR through "Add Remote Queue Manager" and it works fine.

I just wonder why that local QMGR cannot be shown in the MQ Explorer.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Open a Command Prompt and run the following command:

```
strmqcfg -c
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you describe is documented [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IC83733). Are you at the latest fixpack of MQ v701 or v7.1?